# show Latitude and longitude in Text Input Field

Tags: javascript

how to automatically put `,` in Text input field when a number is entered.
for example, input 234556443 on textbox automatically converts to 23.456545 for latitude 234.5665665 for longitude

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Latitude</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="latitude" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Longitude</label>
    <input type="number" name="longitude" class="form-control" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Define "automatically out the coma behind 2 numbers in input type" with examples

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use custom javascript functions and call them on keypress to format your input, I've created the functions for you check the working example below:

```js
function long( str ){
 var longInp = document.getElementById('long');
 if(str.length == 2){
  longInp.value = str+',';
 }
}
function lat( str ){
 var latInp = document.getElementById('lat');
 if(str.length == 3){
  latInp.value = str+',';
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="long" onkeypress="long(this.value)" placeholder="Longitude"><br>
<input type="text" id="lat" onkeypress="lat(this.value)" placeholder="Latitude">
```

Try entering something in Longitude and latitude this will automatically palce a `,` in input